# PySide2 QThread is freezing the UI

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside2

I'm trying to run a long, blocking call in the background with Qt. (To be exact, the `scan` method for [`pyattyscomm.AttysScan`](https://github.com/glasgowneuro/AttysComm).) I thought I should use `QThread`, and came up with the following:

```py
import pyattyscomm
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Signal


class DataCollectionThread(QThread):
    attys_ready = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.scanner = pyattyscomm.AttysScan()

    def run(self):
        self.scanner.scan() # this is a long, blocking call
        self.attys_ready.emit()
```

However, when I `start` the thread (from some logic in a widget), the GUI hangs until the `scan` method finishes (i.e. a while.)

I replaced the call to `scan` with `time.sleep(10)`, which strangely did not freeze the UI. Is there something I need to/can change to avoid `scan` blocking?

Comment: Which system did you test?

Comment: This was on a Linux box. I can try testing on other machines later (don't have as easy access.)

Comment: I do not know what is exact problem but it may be problem with GIL (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). The swig documentation marks that GIL is not released by default when calling C/C++ function, but you need to configure it. http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Python.html

Maybe You need to contact with author of Attys to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Grzegorz Bokota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7475772/grzegorz-bokota), I learned that the C++ libraries weren't releasing the GIL (unlike other C/C++ bindings like OpenCV and NumPy.)

To fix this, I added `'-threads'` to the `swig_opts` array in `setup.py`and [submitted the patch to upstream.](https://github.com/glasgowneuro/AttysComm/pull/1)

This patch was released as [version 1.3.3.2 of pyattyscomm.](https://github.com/glasgowneuro/AttysComm/commit/cf64a76414533ac0979be2178949788ce0a804a6)